# ionic serve not working if www containt many images

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have more than 500 images in image folder inside www

`ionic serve --lab` not working for me it give me following

```
Running live reload server: undefined
```

if I remove images it works fine.

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: why you have such no of image there? .Use ajax and put it on server ,

Comment: i need offline image and in app don't need to use internet.

Comment: you can use sqlite too ,but it is your choice. Are you not able to build too ? If you are able to build then test it on device and check error on debugger once.

Comment: i am able to build but it is easy to develop using browser. i am asking for solution. i know alternate ways.